# What is this tree with scaly bark in Beverly Hills, California?

Tags: identification, trees, tropical

My friend took this photo in Beverly Hills, California. Does anyone know the type of tree?

[image]

Comment: Looks like Beaucarnea recurvata.

Comment: Does anyone think these are two different trees? On close-up the two on the right seem to have different-shaped foliage than the two on the left. Maybe they're both pruned to have a bare trunk.part of the way up.  I don't know anything about trees, just wondering what the experts think.

Comment: Yes, appears to be a variant of the Pony Tail, fully grown. I am not sure there are two trees Sue, but I will take a closer look.

Comment: Definitely Beaucarnea, but maybe gracilis(?).

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Ooops, I was looking at the taller trees! Now I see by the answer that the question was about the smaller trees in the front. Nice of you to check that out for me, though. Your help is always appreciated!

Comment: With pleasure and I am glad an accurate ID was made! Now, I am jealous. The pony tail I have is a tiny one sitting in a pot, LoL!

Answer (score 3):

These are the Pony Tail variant Beaucarnea *stricta*. The photos below were taken ten years ago at the same Beverly Hills park as the photo in the original post.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nicely done! Great Find!